# Excel Vlookup error

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I have a spreadsheet that is stored in a shared location on a website that I need to do a Vlookup on in order to gather certain data. In order to test I have a Workbook stored in my documents. I have some VBA in this workbook but this does not affect the data in question.

The Formula that I am attempting is

```
=VLOOKUP("activated",$A4,4,TRUE)
```

What I need to do is to pull data from several columns in this sheet but I have not used Vlookup in a long time so I am trying to start small. I have formatted all of the cells to general but this has not helped.

I have also tried

```
=VLOOKUP("activated",$A2:$A71,4,TRUE)
```

However I constantly get the #REF error

Putting the following will return Activated so I know that in principal the formula is correct

```
=VLOOKUP("activated",$A2:$A71,1,TRUE)
```

I have looked at the answer submitted in [Excel VLOOKUP #REF Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534644/excel-vlookup-ref-error) but this has not resulted in the correction of my errors

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument is the column that you want to return... As there is only 1 column in the range `$A2:$A71` you can't put 4 as the argument...

You probably need `=VLOOKUP("activated",$A2:$D71,4,TRUE)`

Also you should probably use `FALSE` for your last argument, as this can return the next closest match, if you use `TRUE`.

`Range_lookup    A logical value that specifies whether you want VLOOKUP to find an exact match or an approximate match:`

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

Comment: The data is not sorted and as such this has caused a slight issue, I am working on something to work around it

Comment: Thank @pnuts . I did see that you posted that as well after my edit had gone through... I've never used `TRUE`, I got told to always use `FALSE` (that's why I had to check the documentation).

Comment: Yeah I was using true in a poor effort to get it to work haha. I have 9 items in the column corresponding to the vlookup but the value I am currently getting is a duplicate value 9 times

Comment: My follow up question was poorly worded. If I set it to check the range that I know the "Activated" is in then it works with the correct values if I drag it down. If I do it for the full range as suggested above, it returns the same value across the cells. I need it to give me every instance of the cells next to the cells containing "activated"

Comment: Forget the above, pulling down the formula was changing the start range and therefore missing out the data and copying data to fill the blank info

Comment: @JamesDev VLOOKUP will only return the first instance in the array